# `SCSS` doesn't work after Updating from Angular 9 to Angular 10

Tags: sass, angular9, angular10

I updated my `Angular` application from version 9 to 10. Before updating it was working correctly. Now it's getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/argon.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/assets/scss/argon.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: custom/alert.
            on line 5 of src/assets/scss/custom/_components.scss
            from line 65 of src/assets/scss/argon.scss
    >> @import "custom/alert";
```

I tried so many answers in `StackOverflow` and `GitHub` which it would not help me.
I attached my `Angular.JSON` and `Package.JSON`:

**angular.json**:

```json
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "argon-dashboard-angular": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "styleext": "scss"
                }
            },
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss",
                            "src/assets/scss/argon.scss",
                            "node_modules/sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
                            "node_modules/clipboard/dist/clipboard.min.js",
                            "node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
                        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "argon-dashboard-angular-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "argon-dashboard-angular",
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "styleext": "scss"
        }
    },
    "cli": {
        "analytics": false
    }
}
```

**package.json**:

{
"name": "argon-dashboard-angular",
"version": "1.1.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "10.1.1",
"@angular/common": "10.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "10.1.1",
"@angular/core": "10.1.1",
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "10.1.1",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
"@angular/localize": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "10.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.1.1",
"@angular/router": "10.1.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.2.3",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^21.0.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
"@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^8.1.1",
"angular-file-uploader": "^7.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
"chart.js": "2.7.3",
"clipboard": "2.0.4",
"core-js": "3.6.4",
"firebase": "^7.19.1",
"ngx-clipboard": "13.0.0",
"ngx-quill": "^12.0.1",
"ngx-toastr": "12.0.0",
"nouislider": "13.1.1",
"quill": "^1.3.7",
"rxjs": "^7.0.0-beta.5",
"sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
"sweetalert2": "^10.0.2",
"tslib": "2.0.1",
"zone.js": "0.11.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1001.1",
"@angular/cli": "^10.1.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.1.1",
"@angular/language-service": "^10.1.1",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.5.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
"@types/node": "^13.7.7",
"codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
"protractor": "7.0.0",
"ts-node": "9.0.0",
"tslint": "6.1.3",
"typescript": "4.0.2"
}
}

Comment: I have had that error, I never figure out the cause except that there was an odd/hidden character in my sass. Try by leaving it blank, it either will fail on another sass or it will compile. If it fails in another sass clear that one up too. And then you know where to start putting things back

Comment: is that only way to do this?

Comment: it working fine with angular 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this. I updated all my SCSS files path by manually and build it again. previously as an example there was the path like this which is completely working with a fine in angular 9.

angular 9 import

```
@import "custom/components";
```

when I using angular 10 I updated all my SCCS path to like this

```
@import "./custom/components";
```

after above-mentioned changes appear project built successfully.

Comment: You may have changed your config details such as `baseUrl` to cause this. But also I noticed `"optimization": true` which optimizes CSS like inlining and such.